What should I call this design?
Tha someone help with this question?
A study has 3 fixed effects A, B, and C and one random factor ID. Factor C (two levels) is determined by each ID's inherent characteristic (so basically two groups) while A and B can be manipulated and are fully crossed. There are multiple but unequal repetitions for each ID. Due to some reason we have to build different LMM in different B contexts (B has 3 levels). In each of the 3 model, we analyze the effects of A and C, their interaction and the random effect of ID. Should we call this study fractional factorial design with stratification because C is crossed to each individual? But usually in fractional factorial, researcher choose not to fully randomize one factor rather than they unable to assign a factor.

"Due to some reason we have to build different LMM in different B contexts (B has 3 levels)" - what is the reason for this ? Are you saying that you split the data according to the value of B ? That is almost always a bad thing to do since it results in a large loss of statistical power. As for the design itself, it appears to be a split-plot design.

Without knowing more detail about why you have to build different LMMs for B, I generally agree with Robert. You can estimate mixed modes with heterogenous variance-covariance structures (unique to B and not-B) and likewise with unique random intercepts/slopes for B/not-B.

This study resembles a split-plot design, rather than a fractional factorial design.
In a split-plot design, one factor (or set of factors) is applied to large experimental units (the "whole plot"), while other factors are applied to smaller sub-units (the "subplots") within those larger units. In this particular case we have:

Factor C (with two levels) is inherent to each individual (ID), meaning it’s applied at the level of the "whole plot" (i.e., each individual ID represents a whole plot, with their specific level of C).

Factors A and B are manipulated within each individual. Since B has three levels and you analyse A and C in different B contexts, B can be seen as dividing the "subplots" within each whole plot (ID).

ID serves as a random effect, accounting for the repeated measures within each individual. This random factor helps capture the inherent variability between IDs, allowing for the estimation of both fixed effects (A, B, C) and random variability.


This setup is characteristic of a split-plot design because C is applied at the "whole plot" level (each ID) and A is applied at the "subplot" level (manipulated within each ID, across different levels of B).
Here’s a simple way to visualise this split-plot structure:
          Whole Plot (ID with specific level of C)
          -----------------------------------------
          |               ID 1 (C = 1)             |
          |----------------------------------------|
          | B1           |  B2         |   B3      |
          |--------------|-------------|-----------|
          | A1, A2       |  A1, A2     |  A1, A2   |
          -----------------------------------------
          |               ID 2 (C = 2)             |
          |----------------------------------------|
          | B1           |  B2         |   B3      |
          |--------------|-------------|-----------|
          | A1, A2       |  A1, A2     |  A1, A2   |
          -----------------------------------------


For the whole plot, each ID is assigned to one of two levels of factor C.

For each subplot (within each ID), each ID is exposed to different levels of factor B and within each level of B, factor A is applied.

The rows represent different whole plots (i.e., different IDs), each with a fixed level of C.

The columns within each ID represent different levels of B.
A is manipulated across the levels of B within each individual (ID).


Why It’s Not Fractional Factorial:
Fractional factorial designs typically reduce the number of experimental conditions by systematically omitting some factor combinations. In contrast, this design fully crosses factors A and B within each ID, with no deliberate omission of combinations. The inherent structure of applying C at the whole plot level and fully crossing A and B within subplots aligns more closely with a split-plot design.
